# how to I keep an item in the same place when I scroll?

Tags: scroll

How do I make it so that when I scroll down my sidebar stays in the same place

I have looked around but still can't find anything.

This is my code

```
    <div class="example">
    //stuff goes here
    </div>

    <style>
.example {
float: left;
background: blue;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
}

</style>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
.sidebar{
  position:fixed;
  right:0;
  top:0;
}
```

I presume you want it to follow while scrolling?